# OpsCenter storage capacity graph not displaying

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

Looking for pointers on why the "Storage Capacity" pie chart for a newly added node is displaying as a small white line (no pie just a radius line).

There are 3 other nodes in the data center that show the chart correctly.

I checked the agent.log's and no errors shown.
  I'd post a picture but I don't have an option here.

versions:
OpsCenter 5.2.0
Ubuntu 14.0.4
Cassandra 2.1.8

Thanks
John